# How can I compute ARGMIN or ARGMAX in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How can I find the index of the maximum or the minimum (i.e. the argmax or the argmin, respectively) in a given one-dimensional range in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) and [MIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094017?hl=en) or [MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013?hl=en&ref_topic=3105600) functions, you can find the index of the first minimizer or maximizer (`MATCH(search_key, range, 0)` appears to return the index of the first match, as opposed to returning the index of an equivalent match later in the data). Note that using the third argument to `MATCH` as 0 allows it to work with unsorted data.

For argmin:

```
=MATCH(MIN(range), range, 0)
```

For argmax:

```
=MATCH(MAX(range), range, 0)
```